# WebCam not detected on Acer Aspire 3 in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, webcam, acer

I've been using Kubuntu for over a year now and I've been quite satisfied with it but when I updated from 19.04 to 19.10 all of a sudden the webcam isn't detected.

I've checked out many other posts like this regarding webcam issues and all they say is hit the camera key on your keyboard which should be (fn+camera) but the thing is that my laptop doesn't have such a key on the keyboard. I thought maybe 19.10 was broken so I updated to 20.04 LTS quite recently and the problem still exists.

Could someone help out? Thanks.

*edit*

the output of lsusb is as follows:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Also guvcview and cheese don't detect anything.

Comment: I am also a Kubuntu guy.  My guess is that your hardware is not supported.  That is a newer laptop ( 2019? ) so it should.  Please try a few things. 1. Look in Bios for any webcam settings. 2. Run lsusb from the command line and see if it appears. Post results here. Install digikam or cheese and see if they can find the camera. (Zoom or Viber or any of those will also look).  3. Go to settings and check for firmwarwe and under Driver Manager.  4. Find the exact model number of your Webcam and do a search for open source drivers for that.

Comment: I opened the bios on my laptop and there really wasn't much there. Running lsusb in the kernel just gave me the info of my USB ports. But when I went to look for the drivers installed I ran into a "Digital Camera" section in the removable devices tab. There's a lot of acer camera options but I'm not sure which one's mine. My laptops model number is A315-21

Comment: Great job troubleshooting. Can you post the output of lsusb?  And there is no hard in the Removeable devices section to just "plug" them in and try. Have you installed Cheese as I suggested and seen if it finds your camera.  There is an old program called guvcview also.